# Using same dictionary template multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I'm trying to make sudoku using a 9x9 grid however in order to have clean code i'm trying out dictionaries. After writing the code given below the preview achieves the 9x9 grid. However whenever I launch the application I don't get the same result I only get the last loaded grid.

this is the dictionary that has the following grid element:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid x:Key="GridTemplate" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>

</Grid>
```

Now i'm trying to use this 9 times into another grid into this window

```
<Window x:Class="SudokuWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GridDictonary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />

</Grid>
```

I"m hoping there is a fix for this problem cause i'm out of options :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful to wrap the resource in a user control instead?

This worked on my machine (sans populating the numbers)

Page:

```
<Page x:Class="WPFAnswers.Ans34384501.P1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFAnswers.Ans34384501"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="P1">

<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"></local:UC1>
    <local:UC1 Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"></local:UC1>
</Grid>
```

User Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFAnswers.Ans34384501.UC1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFAnswers.Ans34384501"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GridDictonary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
</Grid>
```

Resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFAnswers.Ans34384501">
<Grid x:Key="GridTemplate" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure but I think this happens because you can't add the same Instance as a child of 2 or more elements, in this case every ContentControl is adding your grid as a child and that is not valid, you should try a DataTemplate Instead.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridTemplate">
<Grid  ShowGridLines="True">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
<Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>

</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hello @bto.rdz I just tried this and now for some reason I get this result. http://i63.tinypic.com/mim2k8.png

Comment: it is because of what I told you, you cant add the same instance as a child of multiple controls

Comment: hmm. Maybe I missunderstood then. What could I do to achieve this?

Comment: @MaxBeekmans isn't this working for you? this should solve your problem

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm kinda new to this concept. How should I implement this DataTemplate in every record of this grid? I just googled this and I see that several tutorials refer to binding on another component. Should I bind every child to this?