# How to change labels declared in dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I have this Dictonary with a userControl attached to it. I succefully added this to my window ( thanks to my previous question on stack overflow - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384501/using-same-dictionary-template-multiple-times) - ) After being able to add data to my backhand I wanted to update this back to the UI. However I'm rather puzzeled on how to achieve this since my maingrid now contains of 9, 3x3 grids declared in given dictonary.

Here is the dictonary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Grid x:Key="GridTemplate" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>

 </Grid>
```

which is linked to this usercontrol

```
<UserControl x:Class="SudokuWPF.UserControlSudoku"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GridDictonary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>

<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource GridTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
</Grid>
```

and finally given window

```
<Window x:Class="SudokuWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SudokuWPF"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Title="SudokuWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid Height="280" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
        <local:UserControlSudoku Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />

        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />

    </Grid>
```

Note: I'm bound to using a prefabricated .dll which already has the datastructure so unfortunately I cannot have a collection of data in the backhand so i'm looking for a solution that applies to every individual label.

thanks in forward ^^

Comment: If you want clean code, make one 9x9 grid.

Comment: @NETscape alright I though it would be better this way ^^. Anyways if I would go into that direction do you have a suggestion how I would fix the problem at hand?